# Manually computed validation loss different from reported val_loss when using regularization

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I manually compute the validation loss in a custom callback, the results differ from what keras reports *when using L2 kernel regularization*.

Example code:

```
class ValidationCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self, validation_x, validation_y):
        super(ValidationCallback, self).__init__()
        self.validation_x = validation_x
        self.validation_y = validation_y

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        # What am I missing in this loss calculation that keras is doing?
        validation_y_predicted = self.model.predict(self.validation_x)
        print("My validation loss: %.4f" % K.eval(K.mean(mean_squared_error(self.validation_y, validation_y_predicted))))


input = Input(shape=(1024,))
hidden = Dense(1024, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2())(input)
output = Dense(1024, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2())(hidden)

model = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=output)

optimizer = RMSprop()
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer)

model.fit(x=x_train,
          y=y_train,
          callbacks=[ValidationCallback(x_validation, y_validation)],
          validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation))
```

Prints:

> 10000/10000 [==============================] - 2s 249us/step - loss: 1.3125 - val_loss: 0.1250
>   My validation loss: 0.0861

**What do I have to do to compute the same validation loss in my callback?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected behavior. L2 regularization modifies the loss function by adding a penalty term (sum of squared weights) to reduce the generalization error.

To compute the same validation loss within your callback, you will need to obtain the weights from each layer and compute their squared sum. The argument `l` from [regularizers.l2](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/regularizers.py#L57) is the regularization coefficient for each layer.

With that said, you could match the validation loss for your example as follows:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras import regularizers
import keras.backend as K
from keras.losses import mean_squared_error
from keras.models import Model
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
import numpy as np


class ValidationCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self, validation_x, validation_y, lambd):
        super(ValidationCallback, self).__init__()
        self.validation_x = validation_x
        self.validation_y = validation_y
        self.lambd = lambd

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        validation_y_predicted = self.model.predict(self.validation_x)

        # Compute regularization term for each layer
        weights = self.model.trainable_weights
        reg_term = 0
        for i, w in enumerate(weights):
            if i % 2 == 0:  # weights from layer i // 2
                w_f = K.flatten(w)
                reg_term += self.lambd[i // 2] * K.sum(K.square(w_f))

        mse_loss = K.mean(mean_squared_error(self.validation_y, validation_y_predicted))
        loss = mse_loss + K.cast(reg_term, 'float64')

        print("My validation loss: %.4f" % K.eval(loss))


lambd = [0.01, 0.01]
input = Input(shape=(1024,))
hidden = Dense(1024, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(lambd[0]))(input)
output = Dense(1024, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(lambd[1]))(hidden)
model = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=output)
optimizer = RMSprop()
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer)

x_train = np.ones((2, 1024))
y_train = np.random.rand(2, 1024)
x_validation = x_train
y_validation = y_train

model.fit(x=x_train,
          y=y_train,
          callbacks=[ValidationCallback(x_validation, y_validation, lambd)],
          validation_data=(x_validation, y_validation))
```